# How to prepend Java Scanner with a prefix?

Tags: java, prefix

How can I make a java scanner with a prefix?

Example console:

```
> //Here the input
```

Similar to a command line of a Windows or Linux shell ? So it needs to have a ">" before the input.

**Prefix and input on same line**

Comment: Just print out that `> `.

Comment: A scanner merely takes in an input stream and parses information from it. It doesn't even know that it is working with a console - the input could come from a file or a network connection. If it is attached to a console, printing to that console may *look* like prompting, but has no relation to the scanner itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just simply print your desired prefix before scanning.

But keep in mind to use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()` or your input will be one line below your prefix.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("> ");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: This code is good, but you might want to add some explanation to your answer. This likely will give you a second positive vote ;-)

Comment: can i do the prefix and input  on The same line?

Comment: @Indra You could write a method for that.   

    `private static String getCommand() {  
        System.out.print("> ");  
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();  
    }`

Comment: @Cir0X Creating new `Scanner` for every input line is rather bad idea

Comment: @Indra @Jaroslaw Pawlak Okay then with a parameter.  
    `private static String getCommand(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("> ");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }`